# Xcode: testing if framework is linked to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm working on a framework that naturally depends on other frameworks. To help my users' integration process I've added a macro that would warn them if certain frameworks are not linked:

```
#ifndef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
#warning "The SystemConfiguration framework not found in project or not included in precompiled header, please make sure that it does"
#endif
```

Problem is, I see this warning even if I link `SystemConfiguration` to my project.

What am  I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User should `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` somewhere in his app, before including your framework's header. `_SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H` is just a preprocessor directive, declared in `SystemConfiguration.framework` internals, so you need to include it's header, just linking binary is not enough.

Comment: Thanks, but it raises another issue: if I import the umbrella header AND I unlink SystemConfiguration from my test app, I get no error what so ever.

Comment: @Yotam, does your framework relay on SystemConfiguration? then you could just link it against SystemConfiguration and you're good to go.

Linking goes after compilation, so compiler doesn't have a clue which frameworks will be linked after it's job done, thus there is no way to check this it at compilation stage.

There is also an option to check it at runtime, with something like this: 

```BOOL isFrameworkLoaded = (NSClassFromString(@"MyClassNameFromTheFramework") != nil);```

Comment: @andery.s I'd like Xcode to raise a link-time error if I can. I've used 'NSClassFromString' as you suggested with some frameworks, but in frameworks such as SystemConfiguration I saw no classes defined, even after searching all header files. It's mostly C structures and variables.